# error "Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different "

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

**Error:**

The instance member 'userId' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expressiondartimplicit_this_reference_in_initializer

**Problem that I am facing:**
i want to inialise user uid(i.e userId.uid) to profileId in the nav.dart so that i can use widget.profileId in profile page to show current user details in profile page .But i am getting the above error .

Please help me out :)

Thank you

**this is nav.dart**

```
.
.
import 'package:justpoll/screens/home_page/home.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/screens/trending.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/screens/profile/profile_page.dart';

class Nav extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavState createState() => _NavState();
}

class _NavState extends State<Nav> {
  UserModel userId;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Home(),
    Trending(),
    CreatePoll(),
    // ChatHomeScreen(),
    ProfilePage(profileId: userId.uid),
  ];
.
.
.
```

**And this is ProfilePage.dart**

```
.
.
import 'package:justpoll/screens/profile/edit_profile.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/Constants.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String profileId;

  ProfilePage({this.profileId});

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
.
.
```

Answer (score 11):

**It simply means that you can't assign one field to another directly.**

To solve this there are several solutions:

**Transform your variables into `static` variables**

```
 static  UserModel userId; //here 
 static int _selectedIndex = 0;
 List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Home(),
    Trending(),
    CreatePoll(),
    // ChatHomeScreen(),
    ProfilePage(profileId: userId.uid),
  ];
```

or

**Assign their value in the `initState` function**  (Best solution for StateFulWidget)

```
 UserModel userId; //here
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions;
  @override
  void initState() {
    List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      Home(),
      Trending(),
      CreatePoll(),
      // ChatHomeScreen(),
      ProfilePage(profileId: userId.uid),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

The above error occurs because you declare your variable `userId` directly inside the class and you are trying to initialize a non-static variable to `profileId`. Because you are using `StatefulWidget`, try initializing it inside your initState() method.

```
UserModel userId;
int _selectedIndex = 0;
List<Widget> _widgetOptions;

void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      Home(),
      Trending(),
      CreatePoll(),
      // ChatHomeScreen(),
      ProfilePage(profileId: userId.uid),
    ];
}
```